# How to include google analytics code in thousands of file with minimum effort?

Tags: google-analytics, conditional-statements

I am developing large project with thousand's of html pages. My website is already hosted in two server i.e one for staging(testing purpose-> in sub domain and another one is main domain)

I also have add some analytics code in all html pages.
But i Want that analytics should only run in main domain site. not in staging(sub-domain) site.

For this. when i update my site every time, I need to comment all analytics code from all pages when i update staging. and enable (uncomment) all analytics code when i update main domain site.

It will take my huge amount of time for enable and disable analytics.

If I add this analytics in one common file and include then actual problem is raised. google SEO can not detect that code. so need to add analytics code in html.

Is there any way to prevent run analytics conditionally by checking host name ?

I already write condition before execute analytics, but I don't know that how to include analytics(required js file) conditionally ?

In short Is this kind of code can we write

```
if(main host){
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async>
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by getting the domain name equals to. Since you use html file you can use JavaScript...

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function getDetails() { 
        current_url = window.location.href; 
        url_object = new URL(current_url); 

        protocol = url_object.protocol; 
        domain = url_object.hostname; 
        port = url_object.port; 
if (domain < 'your domain name') {
    js.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js";
}

    } 
</script>
```

hope this will work for you!